# Sum results on constant timeframe range on each date in table

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum, aggregate

I'm using PostGres DB.
I have a table that contains test names, their results and reported time:

```
|test_name|result |report_time|
|    A    |error  |29/11/2020 |
|    A    |failure|28/12/2020 |
|    A    |error  |29/12/2020 |
|    B    |passed |30/12/2020 |
|    C    |failure|31/12/2020 |
|    A    |error  |31/12/2020 |
```

I'd like to sum how many tests have failed or errored in the last 30 days, per date (and limit it to be 5 days back from the current date), so the final result will be:

```
|    date    | sum |  (notes)
| 29/11/2020 |  1  | 1 failed/errored test in range (29/11 -> 29/10)
| 28/12/2020 |  2  | 2 failed/errored tests in range (28/12 -> 28/11)
| 29/12/2020 |  3  | 3 failed/errored tests in range (29/12 -> 29/11)
| 30/12/2020 |  2  | 2 failed/errored tests in range (30/12 -> 30/11)
| 31/12/2020 |  4  | 4 failed/errored tests in range (31/12 -> 31/11)
```

I know how to sum the results per date (i.e, how many failures/errors were on a specific date):

```
SELECT report_time::date AS "Report Time", count(case when result in ('failure', 'error') then 1 else 
null end) from table
where report_time::date = now()::date
GROUP BY report_time::date, count(case when result in ('failure', 'error') then 1 else null end)
```

But I'm struggling to sum each date 30 days back.

Comment: You cannot place aggregation function into `group by` since there's no any count before grouping

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the dates and then use window functions:

```
select gs.dte, num_failed_error, num_failed_error_30
from genereate_series(current_date - interval '5 day', current_date, interval '1 day') gs(dte) left join
     (select t.report_time, count(*) as num_failed_error,
             sum(count(*)) over (order by report_time range between interval '30 day' preceding and current row) as num_failed_error_30
      from t
      where t.result in ('failed', 'error') and
            t.report_time >= current_date - interval '35 day'
      group by t.report_time
     ) t
     on t.report_time = gs.dte ;
```

Note:  This assumes that `report_time` is only the date with no time component.  If it has a time component, use `report_time::date`.

If you have data on each day, then this can be simplified to:

```
select t.report_time, count(*) as num_failed_error,
       sum(count(*)) over (order by report_time range between interval '30 day' preceding and current row) as num_failed_error_30
from t
 where t.result in ('failed', 'error') and
        t.report_time >= current_date - interval '35 day'
 group by t.report_time
 order by report_time desc
 limit 5;
```

Comment: I'm getting an error `RANGE PRECEDING is only supported with UNBOUNDED`. Could it be that PostGres doesn't support it?

Comment: @ocp1000 . . . Postgres has supported `range preceding` since version 11 (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=914ee73b51fdf65cca1862bdc3b8a38c).

Comment: Looks like I'm on 10.12 which doesn't support it. Can you explain what exactly is happening in the window function? I'll see how it can be achieved in 10.12.

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm using PostGresSql 10.12 and update is currently not an option, I took a different approach, where I calculate the dates of the last 30 days and for each date I calculate the cumulative distinct sum for the past 30 days:

```
SELECT days_range::date, SUM(number_of_tests)
FROM   generate_series (now() - interval '30 day', now()::timestamp , '1 day'::interval) days_range
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
        SELECT environment, COUNT(DISTINCT(test_name)) as number_of_tests from tests
        WHERE report_time > days_range - interval '30 day'
        GROUP BY report_time::date
        HAVING COUNT(case when result in ('failure', 'error') then 1 else null end) > 0
        ORDER BY report_time::date asc
    ) as lateral_query
GROUP BY days_range
ORDER BY days_range desc
```

It is definitely not the best optimized query, it takes ~1 minute for it to compute.